# Does digit_between:min, max in Laravel 5.7 accept symbols which are allowed in numeric type?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have been working on Laravel for a while and trying to write a validation for a form, specifically for a phone number.

For validating the phone number field, I using the digits_between:min, max validation rule

When I input a phone number without any symbols like `+` or `-` it works just fine, for eg: 918569633256 works fine and passes the `digits_between` validation for which min is 10 and max is 20.

But when I input something like '+918569633656', it fails the validation of `digits_between` . Can someone help me knowing if digits_between accepts special symbols like `+` or should I go with regex if I want symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the regex behind digit_between validation and as you can see it only accepts numbers without symbols
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L471